# Marmot vs Groundhog

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras

In English, the [groundhog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groundhog) and the [marmot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marmot) are not the same thing, the groundhog being a subcategory of marmot or distinct altogether, but in spanish there is but one word for the both: "marmota". How can I distinguish between the two when writing in spanish?

---

En inglés, hay dos animales con nombres diferentes ("groundhog"/"marmot") que en español tienen la misma traducción: marmota. ¿Cómo puedo distinguir entre el "groundhog" y las otras marmotas cuando escribo en español?

Comment: WordReference also gives the term "marmota americana" (http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=groundhog ) for "groundhog."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By clicking on the Spanish translation of the Wikipedia page you provided for [Groundhog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groundhog), we see that the Spanish translation is [Marmota Monax](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marmota_monax), or *Marmota Canadiense*.

Comment: But would you use "marmota monax" in day-to-day language? It sounds so scientific.

Comment: @neizan If you see the distribution map, these animals are basically in US and Canada, so a "day-to-day" translation is almost imposible because we never really use the word. I certainly never have.

Comment: @Newbie, good point. But keep in mind there are a lot of native Spanish speakers in the US and Canada...I'm sure they have a word for it. Maybe one of them will see this comment and enlighten us.

Comment: @neizan I agree with you, it will be really helpful.

Comment: For things like this, where a word is only used in an area where Spanish is not natively spoken, it's common to use the native (English, in this case) word.  I could very easily see a Spanish-speaker living in the northern U.S. say "Ayer vi un Groundhog".

Comment: In Spain "groundhog day" is generally translated as "día de la marmota".